# on the proof of a basic theorem on double complexes

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

This question concerns my attempt to prove the following theorem and a point where i get stuck. My working category is that of modules over a commutative ring.

> Theorem [B.2, Matsumura, CMR, p.276]: Let $K^{p,q}$ be a double complex with differentials $d'$ and $d''$ for the first and second index respectively. Assume that $K^{p,q}=0$ if $q<0$ or $p<0$ and that $H^q(K^{p \cdot})=0$ whenever $q>0$. Define $X^p=\operatorname{Ker}(d'':K^{p,0} \rightarrow K^{p,1})$, which becomes a complex via $d'$. Then $H^n(K) = H^n(X^{\cdot})$.

Here is my attempt: We first establish a morphism of complexes $X \rightarrow K$ as follows. If $a_{n,0} \in X^n$ then define $X^n \rightarrow K^n$ simply by $a_{n,0} \mapsto a_{n,0}$. This indeed is a morphism of complexes and so it induces a morphism on the cohomologies $H^n(X^{\cdot}) \rightarrow H^n(K)$. I want to start by showing that this morphism is injective. Let $\xi_{n,0}$ be an element of $X^n$ that represents an element of $H^n(X^{\cdot})$. Then $\xi_{n,0} \in \operatorname{Ker} d'_{n,0} \cap\operatorname{Ker} d''_{n,0}$ and so $d' \xi_{n,0} =0, \, (1)$ and $d'' \xi_{n,0} = 0, \, (2)$. Moreover lets assume that the class of $\xi_{n,0}$ in $H^n(X^{\cdot})$ is taken to zero in $H^n(K)$. What that means is that $\xi_{n,0} \in \operatorname{Im} d_{n-1}$, where $d$ is the differential of the total complex $K$. Hence $\xi_{n,0} = d' a_{n-1,0}, \, (3)$, where $a_{n-1,0} \in K_{n-1,0}$. To finish the proof of injectivity, i need to show that actually $d'' a_{n-1,0}=0$ or equivalently $a_{n-1,0} \in X^{n-1}$. But this is precisely where i am stuck: it seems that to proceed i would need to use the condition "$H^q(K^{p \cdot})=0$ whenever $q>0$", however, it is not clear how to do that. Any suggestions?

Remark: There is another question asked by myself on how to prove the theorem i am quoting:[Cohomology of Double Complex (extreme case)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307222/cohomology-of-double-complex-extreme-case?rq=1). The current question investigates a different angle in the proof, than the one given in the (excellent) answer of my previous question.